# How to copy a function ponctually in a gnuplot script

Tags: gnuplot

The following example explains it all,

```
f(t)=2*t
g(t)=f(t)
f(t)=3*t # Now g(t) == 3*t ... but I'd like g(t) to still be 2*t
```

Basically, I need it because Im calling another script that set functions

```
#usage
call scripts arg1 arg2 # set f(t)

# "backup" f in f1
f1(t)=f(t)

call scripts arg3 arg4 # set f, but also f1 now ...
f2(t)=f(t)

plot f1(t), f2(t) ..
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that gnuplot doesn't have a way to control this "late binding" of the function assignment.

You can use macros to achieve this. For this you must define your function definitions as strings:

```
set macros
ft = "2*t"
g(t) = @ft
ft = "3*t"
f(t) = @ft
plot f(x), g(x)
```